# Send user account activation email to user with OsTicket 1.10

Tags: osticket

In admin panel ->Emails ->Emails in this path there are three email (alert,server support, no-replay) I have setup SMTP hostname ,username,password,port. I have test it from Admin panel ->Emails ->Diagnostic.It sent email .

So I think email setting is proper. but still I am not getting user activation email.

Can anyone help me to sort it.

Answer (score 0):

After setting 'Fetching Email via IMAP or POP' make sure that 'Sending Email via SMTP' includes the correct Port Number - this may not be the same as the one included in 'Fetching Email via IMAP or POP'.
If you don't know your outgoing port number I suggest consulting your email hosting service and search for SMTP troubleshoot problems.

If you include all details above and Save Changes you should get an error if it fails, If so you should post that error message here to help understand your issue.